# 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code, I am trying to get months for a new column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("..\Data.xlsx")
df.head(4)
p = df["Month"][0]
p[0:3]
```

I don't know what's the issue is here but it was working well for other datasets with the same attributes

Dataset:

```
        Month  Passengers
0  1995-01-01         112
1  1995-02-01         118
2  1995-03-01         132
3  1995-04-01         129
4  1995-05-01         121
```

P.S: In the excel data set month values are in Jan-1995 Feb-1995 format, it changed to YY:MM:DAY format because of pandas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sreen\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27276/630478717.py", line 1, in <module>
    p[0:3]

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `p` is a `Timestamp`, you can't handle it as if it was an array or a string. From looking at `[0:3]` I'm guessing you attempt to get the year...? That would be `p.year`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall work for you:

```
df.rename(columns = {'Month':'Date'}, inplace = True)
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
```

Comment: @jalkar works for you?

Comment: yeah, but i still cant figure out the what happened because when I import the dataset, it perfectly showed in YY:MM:DAY, even though its in MMM-YY format in excel and I thought the date values are indexed.

but still need the values as string like 'Jan', 'Feb'.... like this. But with your suggestion I get to know the root issue. Your method get the values as scalar, So i tried to indexed all at once I will get this error `invalid index to scalar variable.`
Thanks for that.

Comment: @jalker it got changed while importing (sometime) you can check for it's datatype. But I hope above code works for you

Comment: The method you gave me is for getting scalar values. But What i am trying to get is strings like Jan, Feb

Comment: imagine with the scalar values If I perform `for i in range(96): p = df["Month"][i]
    df['months'][i]= p[0:3] ` for this reason I want the values to be as normal strings

Comment: Try this:
`df['month_name_str_slice'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name().str[:3]`

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly, and i dont even need to add the above lines. I can add a new column cell with months name and give this data to new cell. `df['months'] = df['Month'].dt.month_name().str[:3]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to write `p = df["Month"]`? In you current code, `p` is the first value of the `Month` column, so `p[0:3]` is just a Timestamp, which can't be subscripted.

Comment: I forget to mention something and I just updated, the reason why I mentioned 0:3 is for the original dataset. `p = df["Month"][0]` is getting the first value from the dataset, and when I am doing `p[0:3]` to get the "Jan" out of Jan-95

Comment: That doesn't make this answer invalid. Check my answer again - it probably applies to your problem. ;)